# what does "slaughter that thing without even trying" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Like any copywriter would, I looked at that and went, “Come on! We can slaughter that thing without even trying.” But we did try. We developed these new headline-subhead combos to test against the above Control:

I know the meaning of slaughter.

Comment: [**Where did you find this?**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-that-confuses-you) Please tell us (and click on the link to read why; I'm not just being mean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably means that it is not difficult to do the activity because "without even trying" suggests that it has been done before and the person/s has got experience with the activity.
I hope that answers it for you. Please click the green check mark next to the answer if it helped you. Thanks